# Socket Programming c - file download

Tags: c, sockets

I am creating a socket program in c. It divides data from a file into multiple chunks and sends over the socket. The data at destination arrives in out of order fashion. How do I manage this. I cant keep all the data in memory till the end as the file is large.

Comment: Presumably you are using multiple sockets, one for each chunk?

Comment: Use TCP not UDP.  If you are already using TCP, you have an ordinary bug.

Comment: I am using TCP connection. yes... multiple sockets to download file from different locations. So they are bound to come out of order. No able to figure out on how do I keep data on disk and in the end combine all chunks in sequential order.

Comment: Create a file the size of the final file. Send the offset with each chunk. Seek to that point and write the chunk. After you get all the chunks, your file will be complete.

Comment: Are you talking about creating an empty file?? I yes how do we achieve that in c.

Comment: There isn't much point in using multiple parallel sockets. There is still only one network. Just send it sequentially over one socket. The elapsed time will be the same.

Comment: Is this P2P application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a sparse file in advance and fill it in as you go along.  You didn't specify what OS but here is an example program of how to do it in linux.

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);

    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror("open");
        return(1);
    }

    int offset = lseek(fd, 200000, SEEK_CUR);

    ftruncate(fd, offset);

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Presumably you have some kind of scheme by which you know which chunks (i.e. offsets) are coming in on each socket.  Use that to calculate the proper offsets into the file and write them.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with standard methodology in such a situation, but afaik tcp is ordered. If you're stuck with udp, you could always just prepend a 1 byte (or less) block to each chunk to specify the ordering, then sort them on the client side using that.

Comment: I am using TCP connection. yes... multiple sockets to download file from different locations. So they are bound to come out of order. No able to figure out on how do I keep data on disk and in the end combine all chunks in sequential order.

Comment: Downloading a single file from multiple servers for instance? Encode the offset of the chunk as the first word or byte. Then you know where exactly in the file the chunk belongs. If you're the client and can't touch the server then you may be out of luck. If the server doesn't tell you what you're getting, then you can't order your data.